# RSpec is failing for a student exercise

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm currently doing TestFirst.org's Ruby exercises. It's a program that teaches Ruby by making you build a code to pass the tests. I'm mentioning this to say that I didn't write this RSpec code, but would appreciate knowing how to fix it.

RSpec:

```
# Book Titles in English obey some strange capitalization rules. For example,
# "and" is lowercase in "War and Peace". This test attempts to make sense of 
# some of those rules.

require 'book'

describe "Book" do
  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end

    it 'should capitalize every word' do
      @book.title = "stuart little"
      @book.title.should == "Stuart Little"
    end

    describe 'should capitalize every word except...' do
      describe 'articles' do
        specify 'the' do
          @book.title = "alexander the great"
          @book.title.should == "Alexander the Great"
        end

        specify 'a' do
          @book.title = "to kill a mockingbird"
          @book.title.should == "To Kill a Mockingbird"
        end

        specify 'an' do
          @book.title = "to eat an apple a day"
          @book.title.should == "To Eat an Apple a Day"
        end
      end

      specify 'conjunctions' do
        @book.title = "war and peace"
        @book.title.should == "War and Peace"
      end

      specify 'prepositions' do
        @book.title = "love in the time of cholera"
        @book.title.should == "Love in the Time of Cholera"
      end
    end

    describe 'should always capitalize...' do
      specify 'I' do
        @book.title = "what i wish i knew when i was 20"
        @book.title.should == "What I Wish I Knew When I Was 20"
      end

      specify 'the first word' do
        @book.title = "the man in the iron mask"
        @book.title.should == "The Man in the Iron Mask"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Before it even analyzes the code I wrote for it to test, it gives this error:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Documents\learn_ruby\08_book_titles>rake
(in C:/Users/Computer/Documents/learn_ruby)
You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/) to use colour on Windows

Book
  title
    should capitalize the first letter (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Book title should capitalize the first letter
     Failure/Error: @book = Book.new
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Book
     # ./08_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./08_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:24 # Book title should capitalize the first letter
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -S rspec C:/Users/Computer/Documents/learn_ruby/08_book_titles/book_titles_spec
.rb -IC:/Users/Computer/Documents/learn_ruby/08_book_titles -IC:/Users/Computer/Documents/learn_ruby/08_book_titles/solu
tion -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

I've tried googling the error message, but with no luck. I'm just starting to learn and I don't have the expertise to troubleshoot this RSpec code. Any help would be greatly appreciated for this student in need.

EDIT:

I'm an idiot and didn't understand what was being asked of me. Carry on then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new Class named Book.

You can create a new file in the same directory named `book.rb`, or add the following lines at the top of the testing suite.

```
class Book
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but that only changed the error to this:


 1) Book title should capitalize the first letter
    Failure/Error: @book.title = "inferno"
    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `title=' for #<Book:0x2cfc268>
    # ./08_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: @ChristopherByrd It needs to have a title attribute. IMO you're starting in a bit over your head; do you know anything about Ruby?

Comment: You'll need to start defining methods that solve the tests. You'll notice that in the index.html of the test folder, it mentions topics about objects and instances.
[some references](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm)

Comment: @ChristopherByrd The tests are 100% Correct. This exercise is creating a class so that all the errors go away and pass the tests. Read up on Ruby classes and objects for better information.

Answer (score 0):

You should had included your book.rb file. The solution you were looking for is:

1. As you see in book_titles_spec.rb there is a line of code:

   @book = Book.new
   So it means you need to create a class called Book

   class Book
   end
2. Then in the first test, it calls method title with no params, so it means yo need to create an attr_accessor called **title** so you can use it as an instance variable that you would use in your title method

   attr_accessor :title
3. Now just the logic to pass the tests, so you can create a title method and use the @title variable to do the magic

   def title
     @title.split(' ')
     #All your logic to pass the tests
     @youranswer
   end

I thought this was a difficult test for begginers in Ruby, so this answer could help them to start solving the exercise.